# how to make a chat room on google app engine , has some demo ? and example?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, chatroom

has any app engine already do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Partychat](http://partychapp.appspot.com/) an example of an XMPP-based chatroom running on App Engine.  And it's [open-source](http://code.google.com/p/partychapp/).

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine only supports HTTP and limits the response time (which makes Comet a no-go).

The only (supported) way is [XMPP](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/), but it only supports [BOSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOSH) protocol, which does not facilitate push from server to clients.

It seems that your only way would be polling.

Comment: Comet is coming; it's currently available to trusted testers.

Comment: That's great news. Websockets maybe?